# Can I set (within the dbase) a size limit on a bytea field in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have quite a few bytea fields in a PostgreSQL database.

(i) Is there a way to impose a size cap on such fields (so that an error is thrown if this size is attempted to be exceeded) by using a database feature?

(ii) Alternatively, is there a good way to do this in SQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a domain (on PostgreSQL size).

```
CREATE DOMAIN my_bytea_8 AS bytea CHECK(length(value) <= 8);

postgres=# SELECT 'NAZDARBAZAR'::my_bytea_8;
ERROR:  23514: value for domain my_bytea_8 violates check constraint "my_bytea_8_check"
SCHEMA NAME:  public
DATATYPE NAME:  my_bytea_8
CONSTRAINT NAME:  my_bytea_8_check
LOCATION:  ExecEvalCoerceToDomain, execQual.c:4042
```

Comment: Or just throw a CHECK on the relevant column.

Comment: For those interested, I found a range of links which explain this: bytea length function (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-binarystring.html); creating a domain (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdomain.html); and in SQL Alchemy constraints (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html); but there are issues in creating a domain in SQLAlchemy (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662846/how-to-represent-a-custom-postgresql-domain-in-sqlalchemy); there may be another way to do this in SQLAlchemy.