# Can you create a custom column type in SQLAlchemy ORM, and impose a max length constraint on it?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, check-constraints

In other words, I want to achieve the same objective as a postgres custom domain with a constraint (in my case a bytea type with a max length constraint), but it seems that SQLAlchemy does not have direct support for a postgres domain (see here: [How to represent a custom PostgreSQL domain in SQLAlchemy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18662846/how-to-represent-a-custom-postgresql-domain-in-sqlalchemy) and my earlier question here: [Can I set (within the dbase) a size limit on a bytea field in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35532100/can-i-set-within-the-dbase-a-size-limit-on-a-bytea-field-in-postgresql?lq=1)).

Comment: What's wrong with adding CHECK constraints to the columns?

Comment: I have, say, a dozen tables with a few columns in each in which I want this check-constraint, I don't want to have to apply a check constraint column by column and have to remember to add it to new columns, and have to alter it multiple times if I decide to change the length cap. I would prefer to add a new 'type' which has this limitation built in.

Comment: Fair enough.  Unfortunately, I've found that ORMs tend to have problems with custom types, apparently SQLAlchemy does too.

Comment: Perhaps it is a matter of creating a custom type, and adding some kind of internal check: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#typedecorator-recipes